# Java : declaring objects in a loop

Tags: java, loops, object, reference

Is there any difference between

```
for (...) {
  String temp = "temp";
}
```

and

```
String temp;
for (...) {
  temp = "temp";
}
```

I mean, does Java waste many resources creating/deleting objects in loop?

Thank you.

Comment: It is not a object. It's a local or class variable.

Comment: I wouldn't rely on this and prefer readability. If temp has to be used only in the for loop, use  the first.

Comment: Your question only shows setting `temp` to a literal string, making it a loop-invariant. Is it really? There's a *big* difference between that and just about anything else you might do with `temp`. I'd clarify the question if I were you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in **scope** of variable.

- Defined inside loop means visible only inside the loop.
- Defined outside the loop means visible inside and outside the loop.

> does Java waste many resources creating/deleting objects in loop?

if defined inside the loop then it will be re-intialized with every iteration, which means an extra executable statement. If you want to re-intialize it with each iteration then good otherwise move it out to save wasted cpu for that statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference is the issue of **scope**. With the variable being declared outside the for-block, the variable (object reference) can be accessed outside the for-loop block.

If the object reference variable is declared inside the for-loop, then it can only be accessed within the for-loop block.

Answer (score 0):

**First the two scope variables.**

1. define inside the loop will be visible only to loop.
2. define outside the loop will be visible to inside and outside the loop

**Java waste many resources creating/deleting**

Java creates as many objects of `String` as many times you are iterating your loop but the reference will be same. So its a bit resource and memory consuming. Use `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (...) 

{

String temp = "temp";

}
```

In this case your temp would be available only for **For  loop**

```
String temp;

for (...)

 {

  temp = "temp";

}
```

And here If you are writing this code inside a method then it would be available  throughout the method.

**Note:-** Local variables are created in Stack and are removed after execution of that method.